# PostgreSQL accents

Tags: postgresql, grafana

I've encountered a problem with PostgreSQL in Grafana when im searching for name in my DB with accents.
PostgreSQL doesn't search for those names and they don't apear in my dashboard, does anyone knows a way to work arround this problem?

```
Select vgtuser, count(*)
From (
SELECT DISTINCT(a.ticket_id), max(a.updated_on), b.name as vgtuser 
FROM ticket_messages a
INNER JOIN admins b ON a.admin_id=b.admin_id
INNER JOIN ticket_status_history c ON a.ticket_id=c.ticket_id
WHERE a.updated_by in('Ana Monteiro', 'Nuno Gonçalves', 'Henrique Espinha', 'Ricardo Sousa', 'João Fernandes', 'Pedro Pereira', 'Luis Moreno', 'Gonçalo Rodrigues', 'Nuno Coelho') AND c.status_id IN(50, 60, 65)
GROUP BY a.ticket_id, b.name
ORDER BY 1 ) as media
group by 1
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

To be more precise the names that dosent appear on grafana display are "Nuno Gonçalves" , "João Fernandes", "Gonçalo Rodrigues" all the other names are appearing great, i tried working around the problem using the LIKE clause but the results were not correct and i couldn`t get it to work properly.

Comment: That's not a Grafana problem, but PostgreSQL. Make sure you have correct character set support in the DB/column. I guess use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` - and it's basically useless if combined with `group by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I think the OP may be getting confused with `DISTINCT ON ()` that does require `()`.

Comment: 1) Do these names 'Nuno Gonçalves', 'João Fernandes', etc exist in the database?  And do the names 'Ana Monteiro', 'Henrique Espinha' get returned? 2) What happens if you run the query in `psql`?

Comment: Must be some other problem, works fine in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8cad05b696d2938e89aefbcbdab748ea

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) The names do existe and when i do this query in psql (pgadmin 3) the result does shows their names but when i do this query in grafana, grafana just can find the names, i think its duo to the accent

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the clarification i just recent started using psql and grafana because im doing a project for my internship in this company and there are still things that i dont know about psql

Comment: @FrankHeikens im currently using the postgres version 9.3 that might influence on the query

Comment: 1) pgAdmin is not Postgres it is a GUI client 2) `psql` is not Postgres it is the command line client that is provided by the project. 3) Use the command line client `psql` to run the query, I'm betting it will work. 4) I'm also betting the issue is with the Grafana client.

Comment: @HugoHora: Are you sure about this version? 9.3 is EOL for almost 4 years and should not be used anymore: Unsupported, not secure, not safe, etc. etc. However, your current problem is unrelated to the version because version 9.3 also doesn't have any issues with these characters. Check the fiddle, just change the database version to 9.3 and run the statements.